# I've created a custom event (EventEmitter<Commune>) that I @Output from a component. How do I react to it in another component?

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I have a single selector for a city among a cities list, and six maps that might be updated (change the location they are showing) when the user changes his choice.

With an `@Output`, in the city selector, I've declared a:

```
selectionCommune: EventEmitter<Commune> = new EventEmitter<Commune>();
```

```html
<app-communes id="communes" anneeCOG="2023"
  (selectionCommune)="console.log('une commune a été sélectionnée: %s (%s, code région : %s)',
     $event.nomCommune, $event.nomDepartement, $event.codeRegion)">
</app-communes>
```

[image]

It's working fine. I'm receiving this log when I do a selection: `une commune a été sélectionnée: Brest (Finistère, code région : 53)`

But now, how may I tell another of my *Angular* component, to react to this custom event?

My goal is to be able to write something like that on the maps that will subscribe to that event:

```html
<app-carte (selectionCommune) = "changePosition($event)"
  [...]
</app-carte>
```